# QThread and data coming from main window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qthread

I have a main window created with PyQt5, i.e.:

```
class PrincipalClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_PrincipalForm()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.list = []
        self.filename = ""
        self.chars = ""
        self.filename_noext = ""
```

I have also a function inside the class:

```
def checkchars(self):
    self.chars = ""
    if self.ui.minuscoleCb.isChecked():
        self.chars += self.minuscole
    if self.ui.maiuscoleCb.isChecked():
        self.chars += self.maiuscole
    if self.ui.numeriCb.isChecked():
        self.chars += self.numeri
```

Now I want to create a QThread class with his run function that I want to use in order to do some calculations, but I need to use inside the QThread class the result of self.chars coming from the main window.

```
class External(QThread):
    
    word = pyqtSignal(str)

    def run(self):
```

How can I have the value of self.chars available inside the QThread class? I know that from QThread to main window I can use the signal way, but viceversa?

Comment: Can you? I would suggest you to try anyway, besides asking: worst case scenario, it will not work (and you might ask why and how to avoid it), in the best it will, and we might confirm if it's the correct approach or not.

Comment: Sorry but if I knew it...I did not ask it here..I don't know what to try, can you suggest a method?

Comment: @MauroMarchiori You need an event-loop running in the worker thread to send signals in both directions. If you override `run` in a subclass, you'll lose that functionality (unless you implement it yourself). You should create a separate worker object and use [moveToThread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) instead. There are [lots of examples of how to do this on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+movetothread+pyqt+signals+slots). See also: [Threads Events QObjects](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#6c678d88cb4b92f3adbd4d6182d6ea78).